How to link storage when "public" folder is renamed to "public_html"?
I am having trouble linking my storage folder correctly using "php artisan storage:link"
On prod server I have "public_html" instead of "public". Thus, I have:
in AppServiceProvider.php
  public function register(): void
  {
    //Public folder name changed with public_html
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function () {
      return base_path() . '/public_html';
    });
  }

app.php
  ->registered(function ($app) {
    $app->usePublicPath(path: realpath(base_path('public_html')));
  })

and filesystems.php
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public_html'),  
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage', //'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],
...
        'links' => [
            public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public_html'), // org: app/public
        ],

But still, when I runphp artisan storage:link, it tries to link "\public\storage" to "\storage\app/public_html".
I expect it to link  "\public_html\storage" to "\storage\app/public_html"
I don't know if there are any other config files where I have to tell Laravel it's "public_html" and not "public"

But why you're creating duplicate directories with the name of public_html? Let it be public for Laravel

@Dhruv, sorry, I didn't understand your question. I don't want duplicates, I just want to rename "public/" to "public_html/" to be consistent with the cloud server folder name.

Laravel apps uses the public directory for files that are accessible from the web. In your case, the public_path('storage') points to project_dir/public/storage. So, I would not use the public_path and storage_path helpers, instead, I would use the base_path helper function (which points to the root folder, aka project_dir) and build the links from there. And I would not change the AppServiceProvider nor app.php, just build the paths with the base_path helper.
